# jQuery storing attribute into an array or object between two classes

Tags: jquery

I have following markup.

```
<div class="block" my_id="1">1</div>
<div class="block first" my_id="2">2</div>
<div class="block" my_id="3">3</div>
<div class="block" my_id="4">4</div>
<div class="block last" my_id="5">5</div>
<div class="block" my_id="6">6</div>
```

I want to select the values for `my_id` in between the `first` and `last` classes and store them in an object. It will be 2,3,4,5 in this case.

```
 var number_store = [];
 $('.first').nextUntil('last').attr('my_id')//??
```

How would I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_id` [is not a valid HTML attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes). You should use [**`data-*`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attributes to store custom values.

Use jQuery's [**`.andSelf()`**](https://api.jquery.com/andself/) method to include both, `.first` and `.last` elements.

---

**EDIT** (*thanks for comment*)

> `.andSelf()`
> This function has been deprecated and is now an alias for [**`.addBack()`**](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/), which should be used with jQuery 1.8 and later.

```js
var number_store = $('.first').nextUntil('.last').addBack().next().addBack().map(function(){
  return $(this).attr('data-id');
}).get();

console.log(number_store);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block" data-id="1">1</div>
<div class="block first" data-id="2">2</div>
<div class="block" data-id="3">3</div>
<div class="block" data-id="4">4</div>
<div class="block last" data-id="5">5</div>
<div class="block" data-id="6">6</div>
```

`number_store` will hold an array.

---

Other references:

- [**`.map()`**](https://api.jquery.com/map/)
- [**`.get()`**](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. What if I want to hold the `data-id` 2 and 5? (data-id from ".first" and ".last")

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It looks like `.andSelf()` is deprecated and "is now an alias for `.addBack()`, which should be used with jQuery 1.8 and later." Thank you. Got it working.

Comment: @steveKim Thanks for comment. I overlooked that it's deprecated. Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use .each() and add the attribute value to array for ex.

```
var number_store = [];
$('.first').nextUntil('last').each(function(){
    number_store.push($(this).attr('my_id'));
});
```